# Redirect to cart for guest login

Tags: opencart

I am trying to implement a feature where when a guest adds a product to a cart, after logging in he/she should be redirected to the checkout page.

If the cart is empty the user should be redirected to his account information page (it is the default condition).

However, I have tried the following condition in this file:

> catalog/controller/account/login.php

`if ($this->customer->isLogged() && $this->cart->hasProducts()) {
                    $this->response->redirect($this->url->link('checkout/cart', '', true));
                }
                else {
                    $this->response->redirect($this->url->link('account/account', '', true));
                }`

The problem now is that it is working when I login with an existing account that already has a product added to the cart, but it's not working if I add a product as a guest and after logging in I am still redirected to the account information page.

If my explanation isn't clear please let me know, any help would be really appreciated!

EDIT:

Here is a screen recording of the issue https://vimeo.com/307006071

Here is my update code:

```
if ($this->customer->isLogged()) {
    $this->response->redirect($this->url->link('account/account', '', true));
}

$this->load->language('account/login');

$this->document->setTitle($this->language->get('heading_title'));

if (($this->request->server['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') && $this->validate()) {
    // Unset guest
    unset($this->session->data['guest']);

    // Default Shipping Address
    $this->load->model('account/address');

    if ($this->config->get('config_tax_customer') == 'payment') {
        $this->session->data['payment_address'] = $this->model_account_address->getAddress($this->customer->getAddressId());
    }

    if ($this->config->get('config_tax_customer') == 'shipping') {
        $this->session->data['shipping_address'] = $this->model_account_address->getAddress($this->customer->getAddressId());
    }

    // Wishlist
    if (isset($this->session->data['wishlist']) && is_array($this->session->data['wishlist'])) {
        $this->load->model('account/wishlist');

        foreach ($this->session->data['wishlist'] as $key => $product_id) {
            $this->model_account_wishlist->addWishlist($product_id);

            unset($this->session->data['wishlist'][$key]);
        }
    }

    // Added strpos check to pass McAfee PCI compliance test (http://forum.opencart.com/viewtopic.php?f=10&t=12043&p=151494#p151295)
    if (isset($this->request->post['redirect']) && $this->request->post['redirect'] != $this->url->link('account/logout', '', true) && (strpos($this->request->post['redirect'], $this->config->get('config_url')) !== false || strpos($this->request->post['redirect'], $this->config->get('config_ssl')) !== false)) {
        $this->response->redirect(str_replace('&amp;', '&', $this->request->post['redirect']));
    } else {
        if ($this->cart->hasProducts()) {
            $this->response->redirect($this->url->link('checkout/cart', '', true));
        }
        else {
            $this->response->redirect($this->url->link('account/account', '', true));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: which you version?

Comment: Hey @AlexanderSemikashev, I'm using version 3.0.2.0

Comment: I update code. I add full code for controller.

Comment: Thanks a lot Alex for your help, it is working now as intended!

Comment: I was happy to help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit `catalog/controller/account/login.php`.

It turns out that if the authorization was successful, it cart is cleared.  I updated the solution:

**UPDATE CODE:**

```
<?php
class ControllerAccountLogin extends Controller {
    private $error = array();
    private $cartisempty = true; /* ADDING THIS */

    public function index() {
        $this->load->model('account/customer');

        // Login override for admin users
        if (!empty($this->request->get['token'])) {
            $this->customer->logout();
            $this->cart->clear();

            unset($this->session->data['order_id']);
            unset($this->session->data['payment_address']);
            unset($this->session->data['payment_method']);
            unset($this->session->data['payment_methods']);
            unset($this->session->data['shipping_address']);
            unset($this->session->data['shipping_method']);
            unset($this->session->data['shipping_methods']);
            unset($this->session->data['comment']);
            unset($this->session->data['coupon']);
            unset($this->session->data['reward']);
            unset($this->session->data['voucher']);
            unset($this->session->data['vouchers']);

            $customer_info = $this->model_account_customer->getCustomerByToken($this->request->get['token']);

            if ($customer_info && $this->customer->login($customer_info['email'], '', true)) {
                // Default Addresses
                $this->load->model('account/address');

                if ($this->config->get('config_tax_customer') == 'payment') {
                    $this->session->data['payment_address'] = $this->model_account_address->getAddress($this->customer->getAddressId());
                }

                if ($this->config->get('config_tax_customer') == 'shipping') {
                    $this->session->data['shipping_address'] = $this->model_account_address->getAddress($this->customer->getAddressId());
                }

                $this->response->redirect($this->url->link('account/account', '', true));
            }
        }

        if ($this->customer->isLogged()) {
            $this->response->redirect($this->url->link('account/account', '', true));
        }

        $this->load->language('account/login');

        $this->document->setTitle($this->language->get('heading_title'));

        /* ADDING THIS - START */
        if( ($this->request->server['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') ){
            if( $this->cart->hasProducts() ){
                $this->cartisempty = false;
            }
        }
        /* ADDING THIS - END */

        if (($this->request->server['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') && $this->validate()) {
            // Unset guest
            unset($this->session->data['guest']);

            // Default Shipping Address
            $this->load->model('account/address');

            if ($this->config->get('config_tax_customer') == 'payment') {
                $this->session->data['payment_address'] = $this->model_account_address->getAddress($this->customer->getAddressId());
            }

            if ($this->config->get('config_tax_customer') == 'shipping') {
                $this->session->data['shipping_address'] = $this->model_account_address->getAddress($this->customer->getAddressId());
            }

            // Wishlist
            if (isset($this->session->data['wishlist']) && is_array($this->session->data['wishlist'])) {
                $this->load->model('account/wishlist');

                foreach ($this->session->data['wishlist'] as $key => $product_id) {
                    $this->model_account_wishlist->addWishlist($product_id);

                    unset($this->session->data['wishlist'][$key]);
                }
            }

            // Added strpos check to pass McAfee PCI compliance test (http://forum.opencart.com/viewtopic.php?f=10&t=12043&p=151494#p151295)
            if (isset($this->request->post['redirect']) && $this->request->post['redirect'] != $this->url->link('account/logout', '', true) && (strpos($this->request->post['redirect'], $this->config->get('config_url')) !== false || strpos($this->request->post['redirect'], $this->config->get('config_ssl')) !== false)) {
                $this->response->redirect(str_replace('&amp;', '&', $this->request->post['redirect']));
            } else {
                /* ADDING THIS - START */
                if( $this->cartisempty == false OR $this->cart->hasProducts() ){
                    $this->response->redirect($this->url->link('checkout/cart', '', true));
                } else {
                    $this->response->redirect($this->url->link('account/account', '', true));
                }
                /* ADDING THIS - END */
            }
        }

        $data['breadcrumbs'] = array();

        $data['breadcrumbs'][] = array(
            'text' => $this->language->get('text_home'),
            'href' => $this->url->link('common/home')
        );

        $data['breadcrumbs'][] = array(
            'text' => $this->language->get('text_account'),
            'href' => $this->url->link('account/account', '', true)
        );

        $data['breadcrumbs'][] = array(
            'text' => $this->language->get('text_login'),
            'href' => $this->url->link('account/login', '', true)
        );

        if (isset($this->session->data['error'])) {
            $data['error_warning'] = $this->session->data['error'];

            unset($this->session->data['error']);
        } elseif (isset($this->error['warning'])) {
            $data['error_warning'] = $this->error['warning'];
        } else {
            $data['error_warning'] = '';
        }

        $data['action'] = $this->url->link('account/login', '', true);
        $data['register'] = $this->url->link('account/register', '', true);
        $data['forgotten'] = $this->url->link('account/forgotten', '', true);

        // Added strpos check to pass McAfee PCI compliance test (http://forum.opencart.com/viewtopic.php?f=10&t=12043&p=151494#p151295)
        if (isset($this->request->post['redirect']) && (strpos($this->request->post['redirect'], $this->config->get('config_url')) !== false || strpos($this->request->post['redirect'], $this->config->get('config_ssl')) !== false)) {
            $data['redirect'] = $this->request->post['redirect'];
        } elseif (isset($this->session->data['redirect'])) {
            $data['redirect'] = $this->session->data['redirect'];

            unset($this->session->data['redirect']);
        } else {
            $data['redirect'] = '';
        }

        if (isset($this->session->data['success'])) {
            $data['success'] = $this->session->data['success'];

            unset($this->session->data['success']);
        } else {
            $data['success'] = '';
        }

        if (isset($this->request->post['email'])) {
            $data['email'] = $this->request->post['email'];
        } else {
            $data['email'] = '';
        }

        if (isset($this->request->post['password'])) {
            $data['password'] = $this->request->post['password'];
        } else {
            $data['password'] = '';
        }

        $data['column_left'] = $this->load->controller('common/column_left');
        $data['column_right'] = $this->load->controller('common/column_right');
        $data['content_top'] = $this->load->controller('common/content_top');
        $data['content_bottom'] = $this->load->controller('common/content_bottom');
        $data['footer'] = $this->load->controller('common/footer');
        $data['header'] = $this->load->controller('common/header');

        $this->response->setOutput($this->load->view('account/login', $data));
    }

    protected function validate() {
        // Check how many login attempts have been made.
        $login_info = $this->model_account_customer->getLoginAttempts($this->request->post['email']);

        if ($login_info && ($login_info['total'] >= $this->config->get('config_login_attempts')) && strtotime('-1 hour') < strtotime($login_info['date_modified'])) {
            $this->error['warning'] = $this->language->get('error_attempts');
        }

        // Check if customer has been approved.
        $customer_info = $this->model_account_customer->getCustomerByEmail($this->request->post['email']);

        if ($customer_info && !$customer_info['status']) {
            $this->error['warning'] = $this->language->get('error_approved');
        }

        if (!$this->error) {
            if (!$this->customer->login($this->request->post['email'], $this->request->post['password'])) {
                $this->error['warning'] = $this->language->get('error_login');

                $this->model_account_customer->addLoginAttempt($this->request->post['email']);
            } else {
                $this->model_account_customer->deleteLoginAttempts($this->request->post['email']);
            }
        }

        return !$this->error;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey @alexander-semikashev, thank you for your help.

Unfortunately your solution didn't work!

**The solution is only working in the following scenario:**

`If a logged out user has a product in his account (he added the product to the cart and logged out), when he logs in back he will be redirected to the cart page to complete his order.`

**However I want it to work in this scenario too:**

`If a guest adds a product to cart and then logs in to his account he is redirected to account page, he has to log out and then log in to be redirected to the cart page.`

Comment: @KevinAbouHanna Um... I checked with myself, I have a redirect works as you need.  I'll suggest another option in a couple of hours.

Comment: @KevinAbouHanna Did you delete what you were doing? Your code del:  if ($this->customer->isLogged() && $this->cart->hasProducts()) {
                    $this->response->redirect($this->url->link('checkout/cart', '', true));
                }
                else {
                    $this->response->redirect($this->url->link('account/account', '', true));
                }